# Rude/angry way to say 'ask away'

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What is the rude/angry way to say "ask away"?
As in:

> A: I have a question.
>   B: Ask away.

When, for instance, you don't feel like talking, or you want the person to ask the question quickly, etc.

Answer (score 3):

- Shoot
- Hit me
- Interrogate me
- Grr (do i need to explain?)
- Eh?
- Yeah?

It's all done with tone.
Even better is: Good for you.

Comment: I've always read 'Shoot' and 'Hit me' as the acceptence of a challenge (not a literal challenge, but seeing the asker's question as a challenge). I can't think of a tone of voice that would make those two sound rude or angry to be honest. In addition to the list however, I suggest 'What!?', which even in writing seems to convey a certain amount of frustration.

Answer (score 3):

You could say **OK, spit it out.**

Comment: Sounds rude enough! I like the way it sounds, but don't they use it only when the person is unwilling to speak or having hard time saying that?

Comment: "C'mon, spit it out!" could be used if the person was having trouble getting the words out.  But, "OK, spit it out" suggests that you're impatient to hear what they have to say, not because you're eager to hear it, but because you're eager to get on to other things that are more important to you than their question is.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "Yes?" and roll your eyes. Body language is huge.

Comment: Yeah, tone too is very important in this one.  "Great!" followed by someone putting down whatever their working on, and moving into an open listening position would be a positive response. "Great..." said whilst rolling your eyes and failing to make eye contact would be a very negative response.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **Take your best shot**.

The implication is you'll get one chance, and that there might be consequences.

Comment: I'd personally say "hit me with your best shot" as an alternative

Comment: @Downgoat *Fire away!*

Answer (score 2):

Any suggestion given could be negative or positive depending on the tone of the responder.

I'm biased toward a simple "Yes?" muttered through gritted teeth, but clearly it's the gritted teeth that's angry and dismissive.

Answer (score 1):

Usually tone of voice can make your response obvious as to how you feel about it, and sometimes the same words can mean opposite things depending on tone.

*"Ask away!"* with a smile and a nice tone implies that you are happy to spend time discussing the issue.

*"Ask away."* with a frown, a sigh, and an abrupt tone implies that this is an unwanted imposition.

If you want the person to ask the question quickly, then something like *"So ask it already!"*, or *"Then lets get this over with"*, or *"Fine - I don't have all day"* gives the permission to ask with the clear understanding that you want it done quickly. Of course, just how rude you are willing to be may depend on who you are talking to. If it's your boss imposing while you're busy - a more tactful approach is better.